# How to declare a Transient variable in coredata entity

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a coredata entity named Recipient. I need to group the Recipients according to the first character of their name. I am using fetechedresults controller. I need a property which I can provide to NSFetchedResults controller to use it as section key. This property need not be saved in coredata. So I thought of creating a Transient property and provide my own implementation of setter and getter for that property.

Application crashing saying no such property found in Recipient entity. Please help.

In Recipient.h I have

```
@interface Recipient : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * namesFirstCharacter;
@end
```

In Recipient.m I have

```
 @dynamic name;
 @ dynamic namesFirstCharacter;

-(NSString *) namesFirstCharacter{
//my coide to return first character of name
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a transient property.  Instead, simply create a method or define a `readonly` property, and give the method or property name to the FRC.

Comment: not working :( I declared a readonly property for namesFirstCharacter in Recipient.h and then wrote my own getter for that, providing the namesFirstCharacter as section key to NSFetchedResults Controller crashes saying "keypath namesFirstCharacter not found in Recipient entity " :(

Comment: I've used the technique several times.  Please show the property definition and the setup of the FRC.

Comment: Hi, Yeah you were correct :) as matter of fact declaring a transient property the way I have shown wasn't even wrong :) mistake was not because of FecthedResultsController section key, actually I had written sort descriptor a line above it and that sort descriptor was making use of transient property :) I read the docs again "Docs clearly says we can use transient properties only for section key path and should not be used in sort descriptor" As I saw the error I thought I was declaring it wrong but the truth was the usage as sort descriptor was wrong :) Thnks fr the help :) Up-voting your ans